# Validate and retrieve some columns from hibernate

Tags: hibernate

How can I retrieve an object from the database with HQL?
I am trying to validate user account with his username/email and password then retrieve his id, email, and username without password.

My code is :

```
public UserAccount validateLogin(String login, String password, int caseNum) {
    logger.info("Begin validate user login");
    String hql = "";
    UserAccount aUser = new UserAccount();

    Session session = currentSession();
    switch(caseNum) {
        case 1: 
            hql = "SELECT id, email FROM useraccounts u "
                + " WHERE u.username = :login "
                + " and u.password = :password";
            logger.info("Validating logging with username");
            break;
        case 2: 
            hql = "SELECT id, username FROM useraccounts u "
                + " WHERE u.email = :login "
                + " and u.password = :password";
            logger.info("Validating loggin with email");
            break;
        default: 
            logger.error("Can only validate with username(1) or email(2)");     
            return null;
    }

    Query query = session.createQuery( hql );
    query.setParameter("login", login);
    query.setParameter("password", password);
    aUser = (UserAccount)query.list().get(0);
    return aUser;
}
```

and my error is:

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: useraccounts is not mapped [SELECT id, email FROM useraccounts u  WHERE u.username = :login  and u.password = :password]
```

useraccounts:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="USERACCOUNTS", uniqueConstraints = {
    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames="ID"),
    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames="USERNAME"),
    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames="EMAIL"),
    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames="PASSWORD") })
public class UserAccount implements Serializable{

@Id @GeneratedValue( strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="ID", unique=true, nullable=false)
public int getId() { return id; }
public void setId(int id) { this.id = id;}
private int id;

@Column(name="USERNAME", unique=true, nullable=false)
public String getUsername() {return username;   }
public void setUsername(String username) {  if(validateUsername(username)) {this.username = username; } }
private String username;

@Column(name="EMAIL", unique=true, nullable=false)
public String getEmail() {return email; }
public void setEmail(String email) {    if(validateEmail(email)) {this.email = email; } }
private String email;

@Column(name="PASSWORD", unique=true, nullable=false)
public String getPassword() { return password;  }
public void setPassword(String password) {  if(validatePassword(password)) {this.password = password;}}
private String password;

@Column(name="FIRSTNAME")
public String getFirstname() {  return firstname;   }
public void setFirstname(String firstname) {    this.firstname = firstname; } 
private String firstname;

@Column(name="LASTNAME")
public String getLastname() { return lastname; }
public void setLastname(String lastname) {  this.lastname = lastname;}
private String lastname;

/**
 * Define the mapping relation by Item (mapped to fk user_id in item)
 */
@OneToMany(mappedBy="itemOwner", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
public Set<Item> getOwnedItems() {  return ownedItems;  }
public void setOwnedItems(Set<Item> ownedItems) {   this.ownedItems = ownedItems;   }
private Set<Item> ownedItems;


/**
 * Constructors
 */
public UserAccount() {}
public UserAccount(String username, String email, String password) {
    setUsername(username);
    setEmail(email);
    setPassword(password);
}
```

Comment: please share the entity class `useraccounts`, also corresponding `hbm.xml`.

Comment: answer added for your acceptance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the HQL , you should use the `java class name and property name of the mapped Entity` instead of the actual table name and column name , so the HQL should be :

```
 hql = "SELECT u.id, u.email FROM UserAccount u "
                + " WHERE u.username = :login "
                + " and u.password = :password";
```

Similarly for all other cases.

Comment: Thank you. But how can I get the value of id and email only?

Comment: It worked perfectly. Thank you so much. I am searching for retrieving data form certain column. If you can have any clue, please let me know.

Comment: @IsabelIsad better post a new question with new requirements and detailing the same, so that more users can see.